# unexpected behavior by dynamically created button's onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I have created anchor(a) tag dynamically and which having an onclick function,which works perfectly but when i am replacing anchor tag by a button.It seems to show some unexpected behaviour like the form is submitting automatically without any validation.
The reason for this is, my onclick function having return statement.I can't find any proper explanation for this, can any one give me the proper explanation.

Comment: Could you post some code? Click edit, copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Also use button type as follows

```
<button type="button" onclick="return your_function();">buttonname</button>
```

otherwise it will be submitted.

if it is not help then in your javascript function. use

```
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you man..it seems to be a browser compatability issue..the same button works in chrome..but seems to be not working with chromium and firefox.by specifing type works in all browsers..thanking u once more..